# Unable to install plugins from Marketplace on Machintosh

Tags: macos, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-marketplace

I have Eclipse Photon installed on my Mac. I need the modelling features (EMF & GMF). When I try to install them from marketplace, I get an error "internal error while trying to show internal error".

```
Unhandled error
    unable to create new native thread
```

Please find the below image showing the error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxqyQ.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.